# Mining a new block in Foundry `forge test`

Tags: solidity, foundry, test, forge

I have a contract with a function that uses `blockhash(block.number -1)`, and I want to test that its value changes after a new block is mined. Is there a way to somehow mine a new block midway through a unit test, or instead to use `Vm.sol` to change the return value of `blockhash`?

```
import "forge-std/Test.sol"

contract MyContract {
  function someFunction() public returns (bytes32) {
    return blockhash(block.number - 1); // Using blockhash
  }
}

contract TestMyContract is Test {
  MyContract myContract;

  function setUp() public {
    myContract = new MyContract();
  }

  function testResultChange() public {
    bytes32 firstResult = myContract.someFunction();

    // <--- Is it possible to change something here?

    bytes32 secondResult = myContract.someFunction();

    assertFalse(firstResult == secondResult);
  }
}
```

Comment: If possible, I would like to avoid forking an external chain, as I would like to allow my tests to run offline.

Comment: Or, if another alternative involves asserting the firstResult in one unit test, and asserting the second Result in another test, that is fine too, as long as the test suite longs in one run is fine.

Comment: I know I can run `forge test --block-number=XYX` to change it, but then it "breaks" the first assertion. And running both contracts with different `forge test` commands is not fit for smooth development experience.

Answer (score 1):

0. First of all, there is `skip` and `rewind`, but they only work for changing the timestamp: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/skip
1. Essentially, it seems the problem is the whole test is executed inside one transaction, so it's gonna be the same block anyway

I would try splitting the calculation and comparison into two tests, pseudocoded like this:

```
contract TestMyContract is Test {
  MyContract myContract;

  bytes32 lastResult;

  function setUp() public {
    myContract = new MyContract();
  }

  function testRecordResult() public {
    lastResult = myContract.someFunction();
  }

  function testResultChange() public {
    bytes32 newResult = myContract.someFunction();

    assertFalse(newResult == lastResult, "Value haven't changed");
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.*

2. If it doesn't work, you may look into `ffi` to save the result offchain and check on two different test runs.

https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/differential-ffi-testing?highlight=ffi#primer-the-ffi-cheatcode

3. Alternatively, there are two more intrusive approaches:

- you may look into changing your function to take other values, that are easier to change, like `block.timestamp`, `prevrandao`, `msg.sender` etc.
- make `someFunction` a pure function, and pass blockhash as a parameter instead. It's guaranteed that it's gonna change, you don't need to test **that**. You'd wanna test if your code gives different values for different blockhashes? Of course, it might be a bit different depending on your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is

```
vm.roll(10)
```

that allows to change the `block.number`

https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/roll